# Is there a benefit to using a calculated value in a PHP constant?

Tags: php, constants

[I reviewed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/248944/120114) [code that contains the following expression](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/248895/120114):

> ```
> const COLOR_MAX = (2 << 7) - 1;
> ```

I know that the OP has some experience with other languages like [c](/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) where such operations are more common and may have benefits for performance or other aspects.

In terms of memory or processing time is there any advantage to defining the constant using the calculated value after the bit-shift and subtraction, or would it be simple enough to just use the value:

```
const COLOR_MAX = 255;
```

I tried comparing the execution time and memory usage of both examples:

```
<?php 
$start = hrtime(true);
const COLOR_MAX = (2 << 7) - 1;
//const COLOR_MAX = 255;
$eta = hrtime(true) - $start;
$memUsage = memory_get_usage();
echo 'end: '.($eta / 1e+6).' memory usage: '.$memUsage . PHP_EOL;
```

Results for bit-shifted, run three times:

```
end: 0.003254 memory usage: 392136
end: 0.003289 memory usage: 392136
end: 0.00338 memory usage: 392136
```

Results for the static value, run three times:

```
end: 0.003421 memory usage: 392136
end: 0.003095 memory usage: 392136
end: 0.003705 memory usage: 392136
```

Any differences in memory or execution time appear to be negligible.

Note: Tested using PHP 7.4.6.

Comment: other than `const COLOR_MAX = 255;` being more developer-friendly, defining a variable will take longer than calculating it so no difference really

Comment: @LawrenceCherone please add an answer instead of a comment. Refer to the section **When _shouldn't_ I comment?** on [Comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: It's probably to calculate the 7th power of 2 -1 without any calculator, in order to have 7 ones `1111111` in binary, and so it's probably more clear than 255, because let's say we have `32768 - 1`, a constant like that will mean nothing, but `(2 << 14) - 1` for a trained eye, will immediately  mean "14 ones in binary"

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ 99% of my answers are in comments when its basically opinion-based when defining a constant takes approx 0.0001ms any answer would need to benchmark it and include the difference between using define() etc. which you should at least attempt before asking.

Comment: some might prefer `const COLOR_MAX = 2e2+55;` and you may need [hrtime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hrtime.php) to see any difference at all

Answer (score 1):

Even in C, it's not really about optimization, since const will be calculated on compile time. Using bit-shifting instead of typing the literal help remind "this will be using this many bit, occupying this slot", useful if there's going to be plenty of bitwise operation such as cramming multiple values in one byte (or in PHP case, in a single variable)

Answer (score 0):

It's a constant value, not a compiler macro. It will be evaluated exactly once when the class file is parsed, and the amount of time/resources required to do so are so small as to be within the margin of error even if you were to benchmark millions or billions of iterations.

There is no consequential result of doing it one way or another beyond the preferences of the meat sack reading/writing the code.